# using decltype in variadic templates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, variadic-templates

I was playing around with forwarding functions, then I found this specific sample that refuses to compile (VC++14)

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
auto test(Function&& fun, Args&&...args)
{
    using retType = decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    return std::function<retType(decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...)>(fun);
}

int main()
{
    test([] () {});
}
```

The interesting point here is that in the main function I enter

```
int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    test([] (int){}, i);
}
```

instead it compiles fine.

Here is the entire compiler log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Text2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\text2\main.cpp(9): error C2974: 'std::function': invalid template argument for '_Fty', type expected
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(463): note: see declaration of 'std::function'
1>  c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\text2\main.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto test<main::<lambda_35d7262d4ab24dcbfd3e70d650f3eafb>,>(Function &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Function=main::<lambda_35d7262d4ab24dcbfd3e70d650f3eafb>
1>          ]
1>c:\users\russe\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\text2\main.cpp(9): error C2955: 'std::function': use of class template requires template argument list
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(463): note: see declaration of 'std::function'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What do you think? Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help you are willing to give me!

### Edit:

I started thinking...could this be a compiler bug? My next step was to try to compile that sample under GCC (on cpp.sh) and it works flawlessly (http://cpp.sh/6pyq)

Comment: Definitely MSVC bug, but why the `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` dance? That's just `Args&&...`.

Comment: Hmm.. never thought about that. I always assumed that `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` was better because it was how you call it.

Comment: Turns out it works fine if I use `Args&&...` it works fine. Interesting, you would think the `decltype(std::forward<Args>(args))...` should work fine

Comment: Looks like `decltype` and parameter packs still aren't friends in MSVC. I reported a [couple of issues](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1125325) some time ago, and they were fixed, but they didn't cover empty packs. Here's [another bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812965) that does involve an empty pack, but the expansion is different than the one in your case; it's marked fixed, but according to [this list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/01/c-compiler-front-end-fixes-in-vs2015.aspx), it didn't make it to RTM.

Comment: I tend to think you should report this case too, just to be sure, even though it might have been addressed as part of the fix for the bug mentioned above. Alternatively, you could wait for a new compiler version to show up on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ and check if the problem is still present there.

Comment: Where does one go to create one of those bug reports?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio. You need a Microsoft account.

Comment: little update here: according to Microsoft they have checked in a fix and it should come in a future release. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1672205/error-while-using-decltype-std-forward-args-args-on-empty-parameter-packs-in-function-type-in-template-in-vc-14